# How LDA does topic modeling

Tags: nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to understand how LDA performs topic modelling. After splitting the document term matrix how it does the document topic allocation is where I am stuck. Please help me with a less mathematical explanation

Comment: I think you should firstly understand the idea about LDA rather than its mathematical explanation. if you can't understand the mathematical equals, reviewing your probability statistics is more importamt if your aim is to be a NLP engineer

Comment: thanx, I have got some easy understandable resources and have understood the concept